# Why does my donut look different in wireframe mode compared to Blender Guru's donut?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, wireframe, solidify-modifier

I have been stuck on this issue for a while and haven't been able to figure what I've been doing wrong. So I was hoping someone here might have the answer to my question.
[image][image]

Comment: well the main reason is, and i know, you don't wanna hear it: but you didn't follow his tutorial exactly. Without doing anything other than he does. I know this, because i often made that mistake too. e.g. as beginner i often scaled in object mode although the tutorial made it in edit mode. I thought: ok, it's the same. And yes, i learnt it the hard way: it is by far not the same. In the end the result might look totally different. So either you start over again (what i did often) or you provide your blend file so we can check it out...

Comment: I don't know why his looks like that at .01 thickness (he may have change his units/scale), but if you increase the thickness of your solidify modifier, you should see what he sees (whether it is accurate or not is another thing). I also agree with Chris on this one, I always recommend that every time you make a mistake in the donut tutorial, close the file and start over _from the very beginning_. Seems like a drag, I know, but the repetition will help your navigation "muscle memory" and it will help you become much faster and more comfortable with the program in general.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't apply scale to your icing.

In object mode click the Icing. Press Ctrl+A and then select Scale.\

Edit: Since your icing comes from your Donut you should do the same to your donut